# Ler arquivo que está na solution em C#

Tags: c#

Criei um arquivo na *solution* do meu projeto. Como faço para ler esse arquivo?
Ele deve ficar na *solution* pois quando compilar ele deve ser empacotado no .exe.

Comment: Da uma lida aqui e melhore sua pergunta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Que tipo de arquivo? Como ele vai ser usado na solution? Um caso recente que precisei fazer isso é subir um _template_ de e-mail, pra esse caso eu inclui ele como [_resource_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx) no projeto.

Comment: Pode ser qualquer tipo de arquivo, meu problema e que sempre que altero preciso alterar esse arquivo, essa alteracao vai para um arquivo que está na pasta do exe. Eu preciso alterar exatamente o que esta no hierarquia do Solution, e quando for ler, tem de ser exatamente ele também

Comment: Cara, você precisa dizer qual o tipo de arquivo que pretende usar. Eu posso te adiantar o seguinte, seu arquivo precisa ser um *Resource*, mas é necessário um tratamento diferente pra cada tipo de arquivo.

Comment: certo, estarei usando nesse projeto um .txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa configurar o arquivo para ser copiado para o `bin` no *build* da sua *solution*:

1. Botão direito no arquivo > **Properties** (ou selecione o arquivo e aperte <kbd>F4</kbd>;
2. Em **Build Action**, selecione **Content**;
3. Em **Copy to Output Directory**, selecione ou **Copy always** ou **Copy if newer**.

Se for um arquivo de texto, você pode ler este arquivo com o seguinte comando:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(@"meuarquivo.txt");
```

---

Para arquivos dentro do executável, basicamente é a tradução deste artigo: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292. Vou explicar sucintamente.

1. Botão direito no arquivo > **Properties** (ou selecione o arquivo e aperte <kbd>F4</kbd>;
2. Em **Build Action**, selecione **Embedded Resource**;

### Acessando

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

try
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var imageStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MeuArquivo.txt");
}
catch
{
    throw new Exception("Erro acessando arquivo de resource.");
}
```

Comment: Certo, depois como faço pra esse arquivo ser empacotado junto ao .exe, sem precisar de esse arquivo ficar visivel na pasta ?

Comment: Se ele fizer parte do exe, aí ele precisa ser um *Resource*. Gostaria que eu expandisse a resposta para *Resource*?

Comment: Sim, por favor! obrigado

Comment: @JetersonMirandaGomes Aí está.

Comment: Valeu parceiro, Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.